# Сортировка данных в sql в том же порядке ,в котором они перечислены в in()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

подскажите пожалуйста, у меня есть последовательность id `(1, 7, 9, 0)`.
Можно ли как то отфильтровать запрос таким образом, что бы записи выводились в такой же последовательности?

Comment: Да, конечно, можно.

Comment: В любом случае записи в уже как-то сортируются.

Comment: проще всего это сделать на стороне php. Это не проблема БД